# Should ONLY ISKCON English translations of Scripture be cited when Traditional versions are also available?

Tags: scripture, bhagavad-gita, sects, resource, iskcon

ISKCON has more or less denied being Hindus. They focus on only a small subset of Hindu scripture but their translations are often significantly different from translations by established Hindu sources.

When English translations from both traditional sources and ISKCON are available, are the traditional sources preferable to be cited at HSE?

Comment: In one word the answer should be No.

Comment: No they don't. Also they have added 2 million words "Purport" under each verse and some people cite this "Purport" as a reference. Like Really!? How come purports be a reference?! Only the ancient commentaries should be regarded (if at all need be). Only genuine Scriptures should be considered.

Comment: It's always No.

Comment: Their work doesn't qualify as "scriptures", we already have scriptures. But commentaries produced by acharyas from that sampradaya can also be used as references just like other acharyas of other sampradayas.
Their opinions can be useful too. Unless they are talking about something which doesn't have any scriptual basis, I don't see what the big problem is.

Comment: This is a good question especially for westerners who are more exposed to ISKCON than Hinduism in general. Should not have been closed

Comment: @PratikBhat We are not here for exposing something or someone. "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise" Just look at the answers. None of the answers which say they don't qualify are sourced. They are answered based on opinions and personal experience. That's why it is opinion based.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma have nowhere mentioned about exposing anything. Mind reading my comment again? If you want the community to grow these questions must exist. If you find problem with answers, why not flag answers ??

Comment: @PratikBhat Thanks for your suggestion. I already flagged it. I want the community grow but not alienating a sect one doesn't like or offensive comments and questions about them saying they denigrate hindu Gods, they changed the Hinduism, their teaching of Hinduism etc., This is really not the correct way to make the community grow. There can't be any source why they should not be considered authentic. It is a personal view.  This question invites opinions and personal experiences. Hence it is primarily opinion based.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma ISKCON came into being after Hinduism so I would not expect any answer to quote scriptures. My point is that this question would help the community at large to understand the difference. We should encourage folks to ask such questions and still maintain the sanctity of this site by flagging inappropriate comments/questions. Closing this question will evoke more negativity on this site.

Comment: I am not saying "quote scriptures". It is impossible to quote them. When there are sources to say that their works are considered authentic, why not a single non personal source to say  they are not? All the answers here gave their opinions.  The question asks "Does their work qualify as authentic Hindu scriptures?" According to whom? Non ISKCON people don't find their works authentic. Not surprising. So, it is natural. It is natural thing. So, what is so special with ISKCON only?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what I will say about this with all due respect. I had been a member of ISKCON for several years during my undergraduate degree (no longer one). My observations are as follows:-

1) ISKCON is a highly anglicized (almost Christianized) version of Vaishnav movements of the olden times (and by that I mean movements of Sri Ramanuja, Sant Tukaram and other Vaishnavas). Why is this an issue?
REMEMBER:- Hinduism has always believed in multiple aspects of single unified divinity i.e. One God with multiple manifestations. People worship the manifestation which closely resembles their own spiritual self. ISKCON tends to juxtapose this to ONLY ONE GOD and OTHERS ARE AT HIS BECK-AND-CALL and somehow inferior to HIM. That becomes almost monotheistic and to me, frighteningly scary. Hinduism is democracy and monotheism is dictatorial. I believe in Shri Krishna myself

2) They have denigrated the Vedas to a worse extent. They use Vedic Shrutis and scriptures only to prove their affiliation to Hinduism and to claim the authenticity of their own cult but when it comes to scriptural authority, since the Vedas are backbone of any Hindu lifestyle across India (and beyond), all knowledgeable Hindus (even those who haven't read the Vedas) accept Vedas as supreme. Not so with ISKCON. ISKCON just considers Vedas as chants and hymns to inferior deities

3) ISKCON Bhagavad Geeta verses are the same as the actual Bhagavad Geeta verses if you read them in SANSKRIT but how many of us actually recite the Shlokas and mantras these days? Mantras and Shlokas have actual power, efficacy, and potency. We just read the translation. That's where the brainwashing and cult worship begins. The purports are way too long that deviate people from core values of the verse

4) Thirdly, they have completely forged accounts of events such as Raas Leela etc. in their Srimad Bhagavatam books almost to a degree of making such a character as Krishna's---an illicit playboy. According to them, Shri Krishna is even superior to Shri Vishnu (who is Vedic God) when everyone outside ISKCON knows its vice-versa. In the beginning, there was Trinity and then all the others incarnated. This is done to mess up Hindu timelines and scriptural understanding on purpose I assume

5) Some of the folks have mentioned that they are anti-Shaivites. That is TRUE. This is evident in their literature clearly. They are anti-Shaivites and anti-Brahminical. However, they have done well to masquerade these days as those that worship Shiva to get to Krishna (who is eventually superior). This is done just to attract more people into the cult

6) ISKCON was and still is notorious for sex racquets and other activities quite like Osho's ashrams were. Child trafficking, prostitution etc are some of the major concerns it has had to deal with in the past. Search YouTube and you will find real-life conspiracies of ISKCON priests at high echelons involved in gross scandals. Most of this is influenced by the concocted meaning of scriptures

7) ISKCON is also notorious for breaking up married couples who are true seekers of spiritual path as a couple. I have heard numerous stories of divorces because one amongst the couple suddenly expects to live a celibate life after having followed ISKCON lifestyle for a while just because of misrepresented Hindu material on celibacy in their books

8) Women and children (especially women) are considered inferior in this cult. Unlike Shiva and Shakti who are equal halves of Unified divinity, the concocted understanding that ISKCON promulgates is that Radha serves Krishna or is subservient to Him. There are modern-day ISKCON gurus who are inspired to make more followers so they would deny this but in their core culture, this is a fact

9) Their (ISKCON's) present version of scriptures are tainted with adulteration as the publishing authority lies with that faction of ISKCON which is run from America. This faction was responsible for apparently killing its founder Srila Prabhupada. There is a power struggle going on within ISKCON and only renegade temple is the Bangalore's ISKCON at West of Chord Road Rajajinagar

10) Even then, Srila Prabhupada's ideology was also against core Hindu belief systems but now due to the internal conflicts between two different ISKCON entities, it has grown worse especially in the literature publishing, profit sharing etc.

11) Other great saints of ancient India such as Adi Guru Shankaracharya are vilified (as Mayavadi) by ISKCON literature Srimad Bhagvatam even though it isn't part of original Srimad Bhagavatam

I would suggest read authentic scriptures from places like Geeta Press Gorakhpur and other reputed local INDIAN authors with strong Hindu foundations and beliefs only. Don't read the translation from international writers as there is bound to be prejudice, the malice of forethought etc. Hope this helps. Refrain from joining cults and channels and do your own homework. Refrain from reading about Hindu material on the internet and especially Wikipedia.

This is not to hurt any current followers but I'm merely trying to explain the contrasting beliefs between actual Hindu belief systems and those of cults. I'm against any cult and choose to learn this on my own from what I consider the authentic representation of our scriptures which is the least adulterated way of learning about our culture. A Guru is always helpful if you find a genuinely knowledgeable one just as our own scriptures say that "Just as the Guru tests its prospective Shishya (disciple) so must a Shishya (Disciple) test his Guru in order to identify Guru's capabilities and whether the Guru is able to guide him to the right path". It takes time and effort which no one wants to put today. I would also encourage people to learn Sanskrit and Shuddh Hindi (untainted with Urdu and Persian words) as well as Tamil. Thanks! Appreciate your motivation

Comment: This post justifies the existence of this board.  Anyone who agrees even partially, please make sure that it doesn't get deleted.

Comment: "4)..according to them, Shri Krishna is even superior to Shri Vishnu (who is Vedic God) when everyone outside ISKCON knows its vice-versa." There are other sects too who believe Krishna is Supreme other than Gaudiyas.

Comment: Excellent Answer. So can their books still be used as a reference in this site?

Comment: All the answers on the site _should_ backed up with sources. Personal opinions will not work as answers.

Comment: @adithskv That is a definite **yes**. This site is a neutral site. They are also Hindu scriptures. We don't ban the work of <put your unfavorite sect> and alienate them. The OP doesn't like ISKCON, the person who gave answer gave his opinions and personal experiences which are not considered sources and talked about ISKCON. They are also Hindus because their beliefs are based on Hinduism also. If you don't like them, don't read and don't cite them. That's it.

Comment: Only personal experience isn't enough, try to cite some sources. Unsourced claims may be deleted.

Comment: Highly opinion based question and answer, yet very Pertinent and important.

Answer (score 7):

First of all I think this question is more suitable for meta rather than main site. But since you have asked, so here is my answer. First we should know [What is ISKCON?](http://www.iskcon.org/what-is-iskcon/)

> The International Society for Krishna Consciousness (ISKCON), otherwise known as the Hare Krishna movement, includes five hundred major centers, temples and rural communities, nearly one hundred affilated vegetarian restaurants, thousands of namahattas or local meeting groups, a wide variety of community projects, and millions of congregational members worldwide. Although less than fifty years on the global stage, ISKCON has expanded widely since its founding by His Divine Grace A. C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupāda in New York City in 1966.
>
> **ISKCON belongs to the Gaudiya-Vaishnava sampradāya, a monotheistic tradition within the Vedic or Hindu culture. Philosophically it is based on the Sanskrit texts Bhagavad-gītā and the Bhagavat Purana, or Srimad Bhagavatam**. These are the historic texts of the devotional bhakti yoga tradition, which teaches that the ultimate goal for all living beings is to reawaken their love for God, or Lord Krishna, the “all-attractive one”.

So, it is a Hindu sect that treats lord Krishna as supreme. And since on this site all Hindu sects and their Acharya works (specifically their commentary and translation on old scriptures) are valid, so surely we can use ISKCON works here to cite sources.

This topic has been discussed on meta previously and [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15424/what-are-some-online-sources-to-get-unabridged-hindu-scriptures-or-to-learn-hind/15425#15425) is the list of useful resources.

Comment: http://www.dandavats.com/?p=8489 "Psychologically, the Gaudiya Matha gurus are not prepared to see themselves as anything other than the superior guide for ISKCON. But they have insufficient ability to guide ISKCON, just as the captain of a small sailing ship on a peaceful lake has insufficient ability to guide a fleet of high powered modern warships into battle on the high seas. They may be able to give shelter to ISKCON members who have fallen off one of the boats in the ISKCON fleet, usually because of inability to accept the results of ISKCON’s collective decision making process"

Comment: @S K Yes I do agree with you on this that ISKCON doesn't follow the traditional Hinduism completely but still their works are considerable like of other sects and acharya.

Comment: I think you are more concerned about Term Supreme personality of Godhead which they use for lord Krishna or Vishnu. But it is fine because for them He is the supreme lord and they don't want to address him by name so they use that term as many people do not call their gurus or saints by their name. @S K

Comment: Since they are not Hindu legally nothing stops them from creating new scripture (like the Guadiyas' "brahma samhita").  I have posted on meta asking to ban citing ISKCON sources as Hindu sources.

Comment: @SK We Name calling or personal attacks are [not allowed](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) in unfriednly way. Your words like "Psychologically" and about ISKCON's ability, behavior are rude. Read [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct)

Comment: @pandya those are not MY words - I am citing (URL provided  in my comment) from Dandavats an independently managed web site dedicated to the pursuit of knowledge and information related to Krishna conscious vision, activities and developments worldwide.  why are they npt a good source to cite from?

Answer (score 6):

ISKCON is a Gaudiya Vaishnava Hindu religious organisation. They are in fact Hindus. But they consider Sri Krishna as the supreme lord (Swayam Bhagawan) and claim to follow the Mahabharata and Bhagawath Gita. They describe Sri Krishna as the source of all the avatars of God. It was established to propagate spiritual knowledge, consciousness of Krishna, The principle of reincarnation, sankirtana movement, etc.

But their beliefs contradict even basic ideas of Hinduism. They are basically against Shaivites.

**Their version of Hindu scriptures are not accurate. I have personally read their publications and observed that they generally deviate from the normal content to glorify Sri Krishna.**

Though the main story remains the same, if you read deeper, many things seems to be different, which does matters.

Also refer this link:
[How False Gurus in ISKCON Interpreted the Scriptures to Justify Abuse](http://web.archive.org/web/20190203200951/http://avalon.wz.cz/Dusevni_rust/Distortionsofscriptures.htm)

I think it is better not to use ISKCON for reference or citations.

Comment: Good answer. Having said all these, ISKCON has a great contribution in the propagation of Bhagavad Gita in India and abroad. It deserves respect in that aspect.

Comment: @iammilind I am not against ISKCON. They have contributed a lot, but they are losing their reputation. You read their version of  Bhagavath Gita (BHAGAVAT GITA AS IT IS), and you will come to know that it differs a lot from the original one.

Comment: Their version is more about the messenger than the message. It message is the essence of the book. But I' m not saying their version is bad, for somebody who has already studied another version, ISCKON's book might seem a little (not too much) weird.

Comment: @adithskv Lord Krishna was not "messenger" you know, he was narayana. He was messenger as well as the message.

Comment: "They are basically against Shaivates." - that's just a view mostly driven by their usage of the word "demigod". That alone does not qualify them as Shiva haters nor does it make them "abrahamized". People who do think that should read other vaishnava sampradaya teachings as well. Of course, some would violently disagree with me... but I have had a lot of association with Gaudiya vaishnavas... If you talk to any mature ISKCON devotee, you would not find any disrespect for Lord Shiva.

Comment: Can you site some sources? Or present some contradictions and explain how they are contradictory? The answer seems just a viewpoint

Comment: @PrakashK I fixed the broken link/source.

Comment: @sv the link is also a personal opinion of the person and it shows how preaching in ISKCON changes words of shastra, it doesn't even show what changes were made from the original words of the Founder Acarya. So I hope this doesn't count as a source on stackexchange. Also if I am missing somthing please do list the relevant passage in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Prakash You're right, you can flag the mods to add a citation banner. Blogs are not preferred sources but they seem to be allowed. See [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/597/2995) meta post.

Answer (score 5):

[Hare Krishnas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2781/6981) are Hindus.

> His philosophical teaching of achintya bhedabheda which are based upon Hindu scriptures.

When their philosophy has roots from Hindu scriptures then **Yes, ISKCON versions of Hindu scriptures qualify as Hindu scripture.**

In [Distinguishing Srila Prabhupada's Original Books from Changed Ones](http://www.prabhupada.de/Books/dspobfco.html), there is a reference which says Parabhupada Himself said that His books which are printed are not the original ones.

> Srila Prabhupada's books can be broken into 3 basic categories:
>   
> 1) Books that he himself directly wrote.
>   
> 2) Books that are compilations of his statements coming from lectures, letters and conversations etc…( these were compiled specifically under his instruction by his disciples, such compilations were put together in his physical presence.
>   
> 3) Book compilations that were put together after his physical departure. 
>   
> .....
>   
> The significant point which is worth noting is that even though some books are titled pre-1978, edition they may still have unauthorised changes to them. To properly understand this it would be in the reader's best interest to read in the Vedabase the 1977 conversation titled "Rascal Editors". In this conversation with Srila Prabhupada it is very clear that his books were being changed without his authorisation even in HIS PHYSICAL PRESENCE!!! Therefore the question which should naturally arise is "among the pre-1978 books, which ones are authorised and which are not?" This basically is the crux of the matter.

So, it is far better to focus on the original versions and rather edited ones.

The same website [Book Archive
Original pre-1978 Books](http://www.prabhupada.de/Books/sp-books.html) has all the original books by Prabhupada.

Comment: http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/other-states/nonhindus-can-enter-jagannath-temples-except-shrine-at-puri/article2764219.ece  "While ISKCON devotees had been demanding entry, the temple administration has denied permission"

Comment: @SK Any other temple(s) that deny them to enter?