# Is ISKCON following Sanatana Dharma?

Tags: iskcon

International Society for Krishna Consciousness ([ISKCON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Society_for_Krishna_Consciousness)).

ISKCON is the anti-thesis of Hinduism.

1. They proselytize: This is highly against the essence of all traditions in Hinduism, Our traditions are to study and proclaim the understanding, then aspirants should come seeking the truth as we see it. To stand to roadside and sell Krishna as though he is a sweetmeat or soap is demeaning to the passer-by, the preacher and the tradition
2. They proclaim exclusivity: Hinduism acknowledges that truth can be reach by many ways and God can be known by many names. It never imposes "one size fits all" solution, no dogma or creed. ISKCON practices such attitudes like Abrahamic religions.

Do we have references in scriptures about such people?  If so, What do scriptures say about such type of people?

**Edit**

My question is different.  I am interested in knowing scriptural reference to such people.

Comment: I believe there are many Qs on this already. I was able to find [this one](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/should-we-consider-iskcon-devotees-as-hindus-or-not/2782#2782) .. I am not sure if those answers will be helpful or not because in all of them users are giving their personal opinions (you can see the citation needed banner added to all the answers there).

Comment: @Rickross:  I am interested in scriptural reference to such type of people.  I am not asking for opinion based answers please

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111147/discussion-on-question-by-srimannarayana-k-v-is-iskcon-following-sanatana-dharma).

Comment: Although we may disagree with them, they are still Hindus as they believe in the Vedas.